# how to know image picking in uiimagepicker?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, background, uiimagepickercontroller

how to know image picking in uiimagepicker and how to modify the picking image or how to call after image picking? and how to get the picking image as background image for next view using xcode for iphone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer [UIImagePickercontroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007070) and use the UIImagePickerController's delegate methods [UIImagePickerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate)

```
     - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController  *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary  *)info
{
// Get the image picked by the image picker
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
//Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the UIImagePickerController's delegate methods:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)pickerdidFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

   // Get the image picked by the image picker
   UIImage *image :[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] ;
   //Do something
   [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Or I am sure this link may be helpful to you:

http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/07/28/getting-images-from-the-iphone-photo-library-or-camera-using-uiimagepickercontroller/